# Syncing x clipboard with yanks and put only?

Tags: cut-copy-paste, register, linux, os-clipboard

I have discovered the joy of having `:set clipboard^=unnamedplus`.

One issue I often face however is having whatever was last copied or yanked be overwritten by what I just deleted.

I don't think manually referencing the blackhole (`"_`) register everytime is a satisfactory solution, and doing `:nnoremap d "_d` (or the same with `x`) has the major downside of preventing me from using any other buffer ever for these operations.

I thought something like

```
augroup yankClips
" Like `:set clipboard^=unnamedplus`, but only with the yanks
    autocmd!
    autocmd TextYankPost * if v:event['operator'] == 'y' | let @+=@" | endif
augroup END
```

joined with **not** using `:set clipboard^=unnamedplus` would solve my issues by only putting *yanked* text to the `+` register, but removing unnamedplus from the clipboard prevents `p` from putting what's inside the `+` register by default.

Given these informations, does anybody know of a way of having what is essentially `:set clipboard^=unnamedplus` without the `d`, `x` and `s` operations going into the `+` register?

Comment: Not sure about Linux, but on macOS with all the bracketed-paste stuff set up correctly, Cmd+V pastes into Vim from the clipboard kind of like like doing `"*p`. Though I imagine that would be Ctrl+V on Linux… Have you considered using `:nnoremap <leader>p "+p`?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I would like to avoid having to do Ctrl+Shit+V to paste, but it does indeed work. I have also considered having `<leader>p` for `"+p`, but I think I would rather deal with the inconvenience of a regular, vanilla `:set clipboard^=unnamedplus` than having to "use up" `<leader>p` for that (though I don't have it mapped right now, I have thought of a couple of ways it could serve me). Your suggestion is very welcome, though it is not quite what I am asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there are two angles, here: either change how `y` works or change how `d`, `x`, `c`, and `s` work.

Here is one way to approach the latter, which I think is the easiest of the two:

```
:nnoremap <expr> d v:register =~ '[\*+]' ? '""d' : 'd'
```

`:help v:register` says:

> The name of the register in effect for the current normal mode
> command (regardless of whether that command actually used a
> register).  Or for the currently executing normal mode mapping
> (use this in custom commands that take a register).
> If none is supplied it is the default register '"', unless
> 'clipboard' contains "unnamed" or "unnamedplus", then it is
> '*' or '+'.

So we can check if the value of `v:register` is `*` or `+` and…

- if it is, then use the unnamed register *explicitly*, which doesn't sync with `"+` or `"*`,
- if it is not, then let Vim use whatever register you specified.

With such a scheme in place for `d`, `x`, `c`, and `s`, the only command that could change `"+` and `"*` would be `y`.

One obvious limitation, though, is that the `"+` and `"*` registers can't be used explicitly anymore for the mapped commands. *I* could live with that because I don't think I ever needed to `d`, `x`, `c`, or `s` to the system clipboard, explicitly or not, (I only use clipboard syncing for `y` and `p`) but could *you*?